# ng serve doesn't recognize -- port option in Windows

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

ng serve doesn't recognize -- port option in Windows.

But it is running while using `npm run ng serve --port portnumber` and is always defaulting to `4200`:

```
oml005@W7-2UA532159M MINGW64 /d/COT-TF/cot-web/cot-web (master)
  ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000

error: unknown option `--host'

oml005@W7-2UA532159M MINGW64 /d/COT-TF/cot-web/cot-web (master)
  ng serve  --port 5000

error: unknown option `--port'

oml005@W7-2UA532159M MINGW64 /d/COT-TF/cot-web/cot-web (master)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Which version of the CLI are you using - `ng --version`.

Comment: I has older version of node, I updated the version Angular CLI: 6.1
Node: 8.11.4 and port option is working

Answer (score 1):

You can only use

```
ng serve --port portnumber
```

not

```
npm run ng serve --port portnumber
```

---

**Or**

You can change **package.js** like below

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve --port 5000",
}
```

and run project

```
npm start
```